# Get all object's values for keys in an array

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
```

and I want to get a list of the values whose keys are in the following list:

```
myList = [1,2,10]
```

So the result I want is:

```
[{name:'a'},{name:'v'}, {name:'t'}]
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?

I tried the following:

```
const result = [];
        
for (const childId in state.frameObjects[id].childrenIds ) 
{
     if(state.frameObjects[childId]!==undefined)
     {
          result.push(state.frameObjects[childId]);
     }
}
        
return result;
```

but Vue console gives me this error : ***InternalError: "too much recursion"***

Answer (score 1):

You can put the keys you want into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This will also work if the array contains keys that are not present in the object.

```js
const myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
const keys = new Set([1,2,10])
const res = Object.keys(myObj).filter(key=>keys.has(+key)).map(key=>myObj[key]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var objectArray = [];
myList.forEach(function(key){
    if(myObj[key]){ 
       objectArray.push(myObj[key]);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over you array with keys and just check if they exist in your `myObj` if they are then you can just push the value into the new arrya:

```js
const myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
const myList = [1,2,10]
const newArr = []
myList.forEach(key => {
  if (myObj[key]) {
    newArr.push(myObj[key])
  }
})


console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done several ways;
One of the options is to loop through the object properties

```
const list = [];      
for(let prop in myObj){
       if(myList.includes(prop)){
           list.push(myObj[prop])
        }
    }
```

Same result can be achieved using Object.keys()

```
 const result = Object.keys(myObj).map((x) => {
        if (myList.includes(parseInt(x))) {
           return myObj[x];
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
var myList = [1,2,10]
// var result = myList.map( function(k){ return myObj[k]; })
var result = myList.map( k => myObj[k])

console.log(result);
```

and if people said it might not be in the list, use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
var myList = [1,2,10, 33, 44, 555]
// var result = myList.map( function(k){ return myObj[k]; }).filter(function(o) { return o; });
var result = myList.map( k => myObj[k]).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

or use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for one loop

```js
var myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
var myList = [1,2,10, 33, 44, 555]
var result = myList.reduce((a, k) =>
  (myObj[k] && a.push(myObj[k]), a), [])
// var result = myList.reduce(function(a, k) {
//  if(myObj[k]) { 
//     a.push(myObj[k]);
//   }
//   return a
// }, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It will cause `undefined`s in the array if the key is not presented

Comment: As previously mentioned on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63019895/9513184), this won't work in all cases.

Comment: so run filter if that is the case....

Answer (score 0):

You could filter they object's keys and then map the result.

```js
const valuesOf = (obj, keys) => Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(key => keys.includes(parseInt(key, 10)))
  .map(key => obj[key])

const myObj = { 1: { name: 'a'}, 2: { name: 'v'}, 3: { name: 'x'}, 10: { name: 't'} };

console.log(valuesOf(myObj, [1, 2, 10]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; min-height: 100% }
```

Or, you could attempt to map and filter later. This allows you to return the objects in the order of the desired keys.

```js
const valuesOf = (obj, keys) =>
  keys.map(key => obj[key]).filter(v => v !== undefined)

const myObj = { 1: { name: 'a'}, 2: { name: 'v'}, 3: { name: 'x'}, 10: { name: 't'} };

console.log(valuesOf(myObj, [1, 2, 10]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; min-height: 100% }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more functional approach would be: `myList.map(a => myObj[a]).filter(a => a)`

Note: `.filter(a => a)` will remove `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
    let objsArray = []
    let myList = [1,2,10];
    for (let index = 0; index < myList.length; index++) {
       const element = myList[index];
       objsArray.push(myObj[element])
  
    }
    
    console.log(objsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
const myList = [1,2,10];

const result = myList?.map(key => (myObj == null ? null : myObj[key]), []) || [];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map`

```js
 myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };
 myList = [1,2,10]
 map= new Map(),res=[]
 Object.entries(myObj).map(o=>map.set(o[0],o[1]))
 myList.forEach(o=>{ v=map.get(o.toString())
   if(v) res.push(v)})
 console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
const myObj = { 1:{name:'a'}, 2:{name:'v'}, 3:{name:'x'}, 10:{name:'t'} };

const myList = [1,2,10];

const res = Object.entries(myObj).filter(([k,v])=>{
  return myList.includes(+k);
}).map(([k,v])=>{
  return v;
})
console.log(res);//[{name:'a'},{name:'v'}, {name:'t'}]
```